# Can't close pdo

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I meet problem, i can't close pdo, $pdo=null not active, thank you :)

```
function about_post(){
        include('connect.php');
        $getId= $_GET['getid'];
        return $sql = $pdo->query("SELECT p.post_id,p.post_title,p.post_by, p.post_time,p.post_view, u.id_user,u.username,u.info,u.avatar FROM post p, user u WHERE p.post_id='$getId' && p.post_by=u.id_user");
    } //connect 

    $about_content= about_post();
             while ( $row = $about_content->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { ?>
                 <p><?php echo $row['info']; ?></p>
                       </div>
                    </div>
           <?php } $pdo=null;
              ?>
```

Comment: What does it mean “$pdo=null not active”? You don't need necessarily close/unset PDO. At the end of your script, php itself close pdo connection.

Comment: sorry i use hosting free, hosting just active 3 connect , if i close pdo that error 'max_user_connections' :'(

Comment: Why do you need different connections though? Do you really query more than three different servers?

Comment: servers notification for me
Fatal error:  Uncaught PDOException: User 'home' has exceeded the 'max_user_connections' resource (current value: 3)

Comment: I don't understand. This happen on same script file or on different files? If it happen on same file, do you know that with same connection you can perform multiple queries? You have to include `connect.php` once.

Answer (score 1):

Change your script in this way:

```
include_once( 'connect.php' );

function about_post()
{
    global $pdo;
    $getId= $_GET['getid'];
    (...)
}
```

`include_once()` is different from `include()`, because if the file is already loaded, php omit to load it again: by this way, you don't have multiple connections<sup>1</sup>.

`global $pdo`: by this way, when you use `$pdo` variable inside the function you refer to `$pdo` defined outside function scope.

---

<sup>1</sup> Actually, this is not totally correct: in your original code, with `include()` inside the function, you have a new connection every time you call the function. Using `include()` outside the function, probably (I don't know what is in your file) simply overwrite old connection with a new connection. Anyhow, `include_once()` is the best solution for your specific case. (I know that this explanation is probably obscure, but my english is very inadeguate. If a kind soul want explain it better, feel free to do it...)

---

Read more about [variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)

Comment: and `require_once` is usually what you want; you don't "want pdo if its available", you "require pdo"  :p

Comment: Thank you very much, i'm learning php,i don't know much, thanks for just me, it activated :)